# Match column values with another table with no common column

Tags: mysql, sql

for example

```
table a             table b
id     name         groupid    member1_id    member2_id    member3_id 
1      john          001         1            2             3
2      luke
3      james
```

and my desired result is:

```
groupid   member1_id   name    member2_id      name    member3_id     name
001         1          john       2            luke       3           james
```

as far as i know to use JOINS either LEFT or RIGHT you need to have matching columns. i don't even know if this is possible to do.

Comment: tableb left join tablea a couple of times

Comment: Btw "table b" structure is really bad... what about normalization?

Answer (score 1):

You need separate `join` :

```
select b.*, a1.name as name1, a2.name as name2, a3.name as name3
from tableb b left join
     tablea a1
     on a1.id = b.member1_id left join
     tablea a2
     on a2.id = b.member2_id left join
     tablea a3
     on a3.id = b.member3_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are just looking for multiple joins:

```
select b.*, a1.name as name_1, a2.name as name_2, a3.name as name_3
from b left join
     a a1
     on b.member1_id = a1.id left join
     a a2
     on b.member2_id = a2.id left join
     a a3
     on b.member3_id = a3.id ;
```

This uses `left join` in case any of the member id columns are `NULL` or invalid.

All that said, you should revisit your data structure.  Having multiple columns with the same information is generally not a good practice.  Your data structure suggests that you need a junction/association table.  Something like:

```
create table groupMembers (
    groupMemberId int auto_increment primary key,
    groupId int,
    MemberId int,
    constraint fk_groupMembers_groupId foreign key (groupId) references groups(groupId),
    constraint fk_groupMembers_memberId foreign key (memberId) references groups(memberId)
);
```

Comment: i see, i knew from the start that it seemed like bad practice.

Comment: but what would you suggest? i already have a list of users but don't know exactly how to make the group table.

Comment: @panzerkampf . . . I think this answer is pretty clear.